# How to search for a string and goto sleep?

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

```
foreach (@raw_data) {

  if ($raw_data[$count] =~ /Date/) {

    @dur            = split(/:/, $raw_data[$count]);
    $durtime        = "$dur[1]" . ":" . "$dur[2]" . ":$dur[3]";
    @dur            = split(/,/, $durtime);
    $startlocaltime = $dur[1];
    $starttime      = str2time($dur[1]);

    # $starttime=10000;
    $count++;
    $status = "PASS";
    if ($raw_data[$count] =~ /Command/) {

      @cmdsyntax = split(/:/, $raw_data[$count]);
      $cmdcount++;

      #Splitting Command name
      @cmdname = split(/\(/, $cmdsyntax[1]);
      $cmdlog = $cmdsyntax[1] . "\n";
      $count += 2;

      #Parsing for command output
      while ($raw_data[$count] =~ /[COMPLETED]/) {

        #Checking status of commmand
        if ($raw_data[$count] =~ /Error/i) {
          $status = "FAIL";
        }
        if ($raw_data[$count] =~ s/\"/\'/g) {
          $raw_data[$count] = $raw_data[$count];
        }
        if ($raw_data[$count] =~ s/&/ /g) {
          $raw_data[$count] = $raw_data[$count];
        }

        #Forming comandlog
        $cmdlog .= $raw_data[$count] . "\n";
        $count++;
      }

      #Changes Added
      my $xyz = "false";
      if ($raw_data[$count] =~ /^GetFTSJOBStatusResult/) {
        my $xyz = "true";
        next;
      }

      if ($xyz =~ /true/) {
        if ($line =~ /.*,([A-Za-z]*),.*/) {
          $status = $1;
          if ($status = ~/ACTIVE/) {
            sleep(1000);
            system("/bin/sh /tmp/uday/cliTestExecution1.sh  135.250.70.161 alcatel Linux1.* 11.54");
            goto START;
          }
        }
      }

      #Changes ends

      $cmdlog .= $raw_data[$count] . "\n";
      $count++;
    }
```

I have two test cases in log file `ActivateJob` and  `GetJOBStatus` as below.

My Perl script currently sets `PASS` as default and searches for `Error` in the below test cases.

If it finds an error it marks the test case as `FAIL`.

For `GetJOBStatus` test case if it is `ACTIVE` script has to sleep for couple of mins and it has to perform `GetJOBStatus` again, and if it is success test case has to be passed or else fail.

I have tried by adding sleep for few seconds and again calling script, but this is not working.

Please help me out in finding the right logic.

**log file**

```
Date and Time is:Thu, 20-06-2013 06:04:19
Line 4 Command:ActivateJob(Job=Test_Abort_New1);
Answer:
ActivateFTSJobResult = Success
COMPLETED

Date and Time is:Thu, 20-06-2013 06:04:19
Line 5 Command:GetJOBStatus(Job=Test_Abort_New1);
Answer:
GetJOBStatusResult = NELabel,Status,ErrorReason,Progress,CurrentUnit,Total
TSS_320_1,ACTIVE,No Error,0,BACKUP.DSC,0
COMPLETED
```

Comment: Goto? Seriously? Please, use some subroutines or classes or anything but that.

Comment: I recommend investing in a space-bar first.

Comment: I have tried to tidy up your Perl code so that it is a little more readable, but it remains a dreadful example of the language. I am sure you don't have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place. It is only polite to present your question as well as you can, and I can see you have spent little time here. I am not surprised you can't see how to make your code work with a layout like that: neither could I.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($status = ~/ACTIVE/)
```

Is not a regex check, the space is in the wrong place. Without strict or warnings, it'll likely treat '~/ACTIVE/' as a bareword string then assign it to $status.

Comment: Nope, it won't be a bareword. Instead, the regex `/ACTIVE/` will match against the `$_` variable, and `~` is bitwise negation. The result of that regex is boolean 1/0, so the value of `$status` will be `MAXINT` or `MAXINT-1`. Still, +1 for pointing out this grave error!

Comment: @amon: Why do you say *"The result of that regex is boolean 1/0"*? It is simply *false* because `$_` is undefined and evaluates as an empty string. The `~` operator treats it as zero and returns `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: @Borodin 1. `$_` is probably not undefined; we are in a `foreach`-loop without explicit loop variable. 2. The result of a regex in scalar context is `1` for success, and Perl's false value (IV=0, NV=0, PV="") otherwise, as far as I can see. The binary negation prefers the IV interpretation of the scalar, resulting in a Very Large Number either way, which is always true. Thus, the `if(...)` is always true

Comment: @amon: Ah I see. You mean *"The result of that regex is boolean 1 or 0"*. As it stands it reads as the result of the division `1/0`, which you seemed - also erroneously - to be saying was evaluated as `MAXINT`.